# HTML & JS infinite background loop

Tags: javascript, html

since i'm relatively new to Js & html I would like too loop a background image, where one of it just flashes up really quickly. The problem which i currently am facing is to bring the whole process into a infinite loop....

```
setTimeout(function ()
{
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'source/css/IMAGES/introInvertImage.jpg\')';
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'source/css/IMAGES/introImage.jpg\')';
    }, 300);
}, 3000);
```

if i put this snippet into an infinite loop via for or while it breaks the whole page..

Comment: just to clarify, you have two images that you want to switch through. Or there can be multiple number of images that you need switching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of two functions which are going to call each other in an infinite way.

```
function firstPicture() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = '...';

  setTimeout(function() {
    secondPicture();
  }, 3000);
}

function secondPicture() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = '...';

  setTimeout(function() {
    firstPicture();
  }, 300);
}

firstPicture();
```

---

Or in one function

```
var pictureState = false;

function pictureChanging() {
  var timeout;

  if (pictureState) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = '...';

    timeout = 3000;
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = '...';

    timeout = 300;
  }

  pictureState = !pictureState;

  setTimeout(function() {
    pictureChanging();
  }, timeout);
}

pictureChanging();
```

Comment: thank u very much, they both worked as intended. I tried a similar one as the first but mine didn't work by any means

Comment: You should open a new question for that. It's unrelated with the function I described for you, it's css modification stuff now.